# Typescript compilation: Using Webpack with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-2017

we have a typescript project which is being developed in Visual Studio 2017. Originally it used webpack for compilation because it gives us:

- module system (sorts out the logic behind connecting files to the node_modules they use)
- bundling
- tree shaking

We now also use the Visual Studio compilation because it gives us:

- Find all references
- Goto definition

The problem is that both compilers together noticeably slow down the compilation process. The simple solution would surely be to disable VS, such as by putting this attribute in the csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But then we lose the find all references and goto definition functionality, which is pretty much the main reasons we switched to typescript in the first place.

Does anyone else have experience with this problem? We are mainly looking to keep the VS functionality, but disable any javascript files being output, as they slow the compilation process way down and go unused anyway.

We've also tried removing webpack from the equation, but have found the 'tsc' compiler alone doesn't cover all the functionality that webpack gave us.